# How can I change frame or size of WKInterfaceImage object for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfaceimage

How can I change size of WKInterfaceImage object? Official documentation doesn't provide any way to do this simple step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UIImage` you provide to a `WKInterfaceImage` should already have the desired size. If it doesn't, resize it on the iPhone before sending it to the watch.

If you want to change the size anyway, call `setWidth(_:)` and `setHeight(_:)`. This will also change the scaling mode of your image to "scale to fill".

Comment: I want to change frame of the container for image.

Comment: Call `setWidth(_:)` and `setHeight(_:)`, but this is usually not optimal.